# Is it possible to configure ckeditor create <p> on two Enters?

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to configure CKEditor to create <br> on <kbd>Enter</kbd> and  <p> on <kbd>Enter + Enter</kbd>?
What consequences might be if I change CKEditor to work like this?